# How to write/read X509 certificate in javacard 2.2.1

Tags: javacard

I want to store three certificates.

I've got two related questions:

1. how to write method `Get_Offset_Read()`, `Get_Offset_Write()` and      calculate offset in buffer for write and read in buffer?
2. I use an `ObjectArray` to store certificate data. Is that a correct way of storing such data?

---

Here's the code:

```
public class writeApplet extends Applet {
     private Object[] FileArray;
     private byte  FileCount;
     private writeApplet() {
     FileArray=new Object[3];
     FileCount=0;
     }
     public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
        throws ISOException {
      new writeApplet().register();
     }
     public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
    //….   
     }

     private void ReadBinaryData(APDU apdu)
      {

      //How to write Get_Offset_Read();
       short offset = Get_Offset_Read();

        byte[] buf= apdu.getBuffer();

       // p1value is certificate index in FileArray 
       byte p1value=buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1];

       byte[] FileObj=(byte[]) FileArray[p1value];

        short le = apdu.setOutgoing();

        boolean eof = false;
        if((short)(FileObj.length - offset) < le) {
        le = (short)(FileObj.length - offset);
        eof = true;
       }

       apdu.setOutgoingLength(le);
       apdu.sendBytesLong(FileObj, offset, le);

       if(eof)
       {
         ISOException.throwIt(SW_END_OF_FILE);
       }
      }

    private void WriteBinaryData(APDU apdu)
    {
       if(FileCount==3)
       {
         ISOException.throwIt(SW_END_OF_ThreeFILES);
       }
       byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
       short offset =Get_Offset_Write();
       byte lc=buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
       if((short)(offset + lc) >((byte[])FileArray[FileCount]).length)
       {
         ISOException.throwIt(SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
       }
       apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
      Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA,(byte[]);
      FileArray[FileCount],offset,lc);                                          
      FileCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking or what your intentions are

Comment: Thank you for answer me. certificate data is more than 256 thus for example write:  I should get multiple apdu. I don't know How to write  Get_Offset_Write().  these methods  should return  offset for write data for each apdu

Comment: That code made my eyes water... Please try and follow the Java Code Conventions of Sun at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to store persistent arrays in an object array is certainly not wrong. So the rest of this answer will focus on the offset issue.

---

Generally file operations are is implemented by following the ISO 7816-4 specifications.

In that case you've got a minimum of three - not two - methods to create:

- `CREATE FILE` - creates a file (of a certain size)
- `UPDATE BINARY` - writes (part of) a file using the offset in P1/P2
- `READ BINARY` - reads (part of) a file using the offset in P1/P2

The offset indicated is of course the offset *in the file* rather than the offset in the buffer.

I'll skip the `UPDATE BINARY` and `READ BINARY` with Odd INS as they are generally only needed for files over 32KiB.

---

If you want to keep to your current design then you could store the offset in the command data (CDATA) section. Alternatively you could write the file in blocks of a certain size and indicate the block number in P2.

In my opinion an addition CREATE FILE command should be preferred. Currently the methods for reading and creation/writing of the file are not symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. excuse me I don't undrestand why create file is need? I Initialize my object array in   FileArray=new Object[3] at the first. and question 2: can you give me link Java Code Conventions of Sun  I can not find it. question 3:I don't undrestand "UPDATE BINARY and READ BINARY with Odd INS" what is relation between INS and update/read binary.